# Ubuntu 22.04 freeze. Does not come back from suspension

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management, freeze

For a while now, I've experienced a recurring issue where I stop using my laptop, close the lid (putting it in suspension), and when I reopen it, it doesn't wake up from suspension and doesn't respond to any keys. My only option is to reboot it. Upon rebooting, I find system update messages waiting for me.

I don't see any error messages, but normally, when I close the laptop and then reopen it, it simply wakes up. However, when it reboots like this, I don't see any error messages, and I don't have any other options.

Perhaps disabling automatic updates (which I wouldn't prefer, really).
Option 2 would be to change the behaviour when I close the lid (hibernation instead of suspension?)?

My system:

- GNU/Linux Ubuntu 22.04 X86_64 Laptop: Exo SmartPro Q3
- Intel® Core™ i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
- Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
- RAM 12,0 GiB SODIMM DDR4 2400 (that's weird caus I have 2 X 8Gb)
- HD 1,0 TB

Thanks in advance.

PS: I don't know how to check what happens when this happens. How can I read the log or whatever, next time I have this issue?

---

**Edit:**

I have some logs, but I can't really see some line that says "error" or something like this. I paste some lines about the time the laptop sleeps and when I try to turn it on.

Here is what `/var/log/syslog` says:

```
Nov 24 18:58:05 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Nov 24 18:58:05 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Nov 24 18:58:06 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 24 18:58:06 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Nov 24 18:58:06 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd-sleep[15992]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Nov 24 18:58:06 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [19073.404531] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Nov 24 18:58:06 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Nov 24 18:58:07 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 24 18:58:07 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Nov 25 10:24:34 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 systemd-modules-load[285]: Inserted module 'lp'
Nov 25 10:24:34 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf4, date = 2023-02-22
Nov 25 10:24:34 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 6.2.0-37-generic (buildd@bos03-amd64-055) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1-generic 6.2.16)
Nov 25 10:24:34 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic root=UUID=79d1311f-3638-488a-993f-a8cc6f76c180 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

And here is the content of `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
Nov 24 18:58:05 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [19073.222551] exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 24 18:58:06 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [19073.404531] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Nov 25 10:24:34 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf4, date = 2023-02-22
Nov 25 10:24:34 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 6.2.0-37-generic (buildd@bos03-amd64-055) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1-generic 6.2.16)
Nov 25 10:24:34 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic root=UUID=79d1311f-3638-488a-993f-a8cc6f76c180 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Nov 25 10:24:34 papucho-Smart-Pro-Q3 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
```

Do these logs say something important? (I have the rest of the logs, but I don't know if it's ok to share them here, or how it should be done)

Comment: You can check the system logs (with other important logs) following the steps on this page: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#1-overview Next time you have the issue try to take a look into the system and kernel logs to see if you can find the root of the issue.